# Extract Parameters from pdo query

Tags: sql, pdo, parameters

I have this query using pdo:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :name AND age > :age1 AND age < :age2
```

how can I extract the parameters from this query with a regular expression in order to get an array similar to:

```
$arr[0] => name,
$arr[1] => age1,
$arr[2] => age2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size..

```
(:[^\s]*)\s?
```

Here is a demo to this REGEX in action using regexr.com

http://regexr.com/39gnv

And here is a demo in PHP

**test.php**

```
$query="Select * from users where name like :name and age > :age1 and age < :age2";
preg_match_all('/(:[^\s]*)\s?/',$query,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output of `php test.php`**

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => :name
                [1] => :age1
                [2] => :age2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => :name
                [1] => :age1
                [2] => :age2
            )

    )
```

Comment: Thank you! Why returns 2 times the results?

Comment: I believe the first array is the matching subject (the field with the optional trailing space), and the second is the matched capture groups (the field without the optional trailing space).

Comment: for more accurate results    preg_match_all('/(:[^\s\b\,\)\']*)(?=[\s\b\,\)\'])?/',$query,$matches);